ROKS calculation for singlet/triplet
ROKS methodology should allow for the calculation of spin-polarized states by dividing the problem in two, one with paired electrons to form doubly occupied orbitals (thus having opposite spins) and one with unrestricted spin properties.
However, I got to understand that ROKS also calculates what is called 'purified singlet state'. I could not find a clear (yet simple) explanation of this. Does this apply to the second unrestricted problem described before? Moreover, I found that many times ROKS is used for triplet, does this mean that there is a 'purified triplet state'?
